# Convert DateTime String to UTC in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string like this:

```
"2010-01-01 12:30:00"
```

I need that to convert to UTC from the current local time zone.

I tried this, but it seems to think that the string is already UTC.

```
"2010-01-01 12:30:00".to_datetime.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)")
=> Fri, 01 Jan 2010 06:30:00 CST -06:00
```

I am not sure where to go from here.

added this from my comment:

```
>> Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
=> "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
>> Time.parse("2010-10-27 00:00:00").getutc
=> Wed Oct 27 06:00:00 UTC 2010
>> Time.zone = "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"
=> "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"
>> Time.parse("2010-10-27 00:00:00").getutc
=> Wed Oct 27 06:00:00 UTC 2010
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
Time.parse("2010-01-01 12:30:00").getutc
```

**EDIT**

(grinding teeth while thinking about the nightmare which is Ruby/Rails date/time handling)

OK, how about this:

```
Time.zone.parse("2010-01-01 12:30:00").utc
```

Note that `Time.zone.parse` returns a `DateTime`, while appending the `.utc` gives you a `Time`. There are differences, so beware.

Also, Time.zone is part of Rails (ActiveSupport), not Ruby. Just so you know.

Comment: maybe I spoke too soon.  It doesn't change the time based on the config.time_zone.  I will add some code above for reference.

Comment: See my edit. (Extra characters added for SO to allow posting of this comment. Blah blah I am the walrus Etc and so on)

Comment: that has to be the best comment I have read in a long time.  It confused the crap out of me at first, but great now that I understand.  Thank you for the answer, that worked.  I am starting to feel the love with Rails dates/times...

Comment: What's wrong with the first version not using zone, I am completely confused?

Comment: The first version works, but only for the current time zone (as defined by the operating system). The OP wants to let each request be in a different time zone, and for that we have to use the Rails TimeWithZone library, which is mixed into Ruby's Time library. Calling `Time.zone` sets the time zone for the operation to the one specified by setting `Time.zone = "some zone"`. `Time.zone.parse` builds a DateTime object in "some zone". `utc` converts the result to the UTC time zone. This allows the incoming web request to specify a local time, but store it as UTC in the database.

Answer (score 13):

In **Rails 4 and above** you can directly use [`in_time_zone`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/String/in_time_zone)

```
"2010-01-01 12:30:00".in_time_zone
#=> Fri, 01 Jan 2010 12:30:00 EST -05:00

"2010-01-01 12:30:00".in_time_zone.utc
#=> 2010-01-01 17:30:00 UTC
```

Comment: Not adding awfully more to the question's context, but this is possible as well `timestamp.in_time_zone('UTC')`, and then `timestamp.in_time_zone('Europe/Athens')`

Answer (score 12):

For APIs you can use:

```
utc_date = Time.parse("2013-05-31 00:00").utc.iso8601 #=> Result will be: 2013-05-30T21:00:00Z
```

You can check these articles:

- [Working with time zones in Ruby on Rails](http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails)
- [ISO8601 - Dates In Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2009/10/25/iso8601-dates-in-ruby/)