# Rails Form Timezone ignored when saving record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am having a problem with Rails Forms timezones.

I have a form that is used to setup Schedules. The form itself is quite simple and is given below.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3>Create a new schedule</h3>
    <%= bootstrap_form_for(@schedule,label_errors: true, inline_errors: true) do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :title,required:true %>
            <%= f.text_field :description,required:true %>
            <%= f.datetime_local_field :start_time,required:true %>
            <%= f.datetime_local_field :end_time,required:true %>
            <%= f.text_field :cost_cents,required:true %>
            <%= f.button :submit %>
          <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my `config/application.rb,` I have set the timezone information as follows.

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

For the user, from the UI, they would be seeing a standard way to pick the date and time.

[image]

What is happening is that suppose i pick July 21 2018 04:00 PM as the start time and July 21 2018 05:00 PM as the end time, and since I am in IST time zone (+0530), what I expect is the database to store the data in UTC time by doing the appropriate conversions.

Instead what is happening is that the timezone is completely ignored and the time set on the form is being taken as UTC time and stored.

This is what I see in the Rails console

The incoming request is

```
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"W1W6naJhEmXhqOJOBBhzQ3O+/HpHrP2WtVNtND+Yoh6mvgsTNr+2GG6T5FxDPRp+DyJAIA+esTpXw8HrDQ60Zw==", 
"schedule"=>{"title"=>"Test", "description"=>"Test 2",
 "start_time"=>"2018-07-21T16:00", 
"end_time"=>"2018-07-21T17:00",
 "cost_cents"=>"0"}, "button"=>""}
```

and the SQL generated is

```
        INSERT INTO "schedules" ("title", "description", "start_time", "end_time",
     "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
     RETURNING "id"  [["title", "Test"], ["description", "Test 2"], ["start_time", 
    "2018-07-21 16:00:00"], ["end_time", "2018-07-21 17:00:00"], ["user_id", 
    "8f4499ed-fa6f-43b8-be3e-228e3ed57fc6"], ["created_at", "2018-07-21 08:16:38.496829"], 
["updated_at", "2018-07-21 08:16:38.496829"]]
```

My question is,

How do I ensure that the the start_time and end_time values being passed from the browser get converted to UTC before saving?

Is there a way to change the value before being submitted from the browser so that Rails can take care of the appropriate conversion?

Comment: Try with callbacks in model, like `before_save`

Comment: @iGian - Not sure how that would help. The problem seems to be that the date parameter being sent has no timezone information. I have updated the question with the incoming parameters

Comment: add a callback as iGlian said in before_save. In that callback you can add as self. start_time = Time.parse(self.start_time).getutc

Comment: I did, but that is not working..
self.start_time is Sat, 21 Jul 2018 18:00:00 UTC +00:00
Time.parse(self.start_time.to_s) is 2018-07-21 18:00:00 UTC

Like i mentioned earlier, the problem is that self.start_time should be in IST

Answer (score 0):

As per comments to your answer, try this:

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :convert_start_end_times_to_utc

  private
    def convert_start_end_times_to_utc
      start_time = Time.parse(start_time).getutc
      end_time = Time.parse(end_time).getutc
    end

end
```

`before_save` callback calls the correspondent method (`convert_start_end_times_to_utc`) which manipulates the attributes of the model. In this case `start_time` (`self.start_time`) and `end_time` (`self.end_time`). This is done before to save the record to database.

For callbacks see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

See this post for converting to utc: [Convert DateTime String to UTC in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046289/convert-datetime-string-to-utc-in-rails)

Comment: I did, but that is not working..
self.start_time is Sat, 21 Jul 2018 18:00:00 UTC +00:00
Time.parse(self.start_time.to_s) is 2018-07-21 18:00:00 UTC

Like i mentioned earlier, the problem is that self.start_time should be in IST

Comment: Sorry I assumed it already was. In this case I think you need to work on the form, see the last part of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389002/5239030

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I have this working. Please let me know if this is on the right track.

What I did was add the `momentjs-rails` gem to my project. This gave me access to moment objects on the client side.

Then I modified the form so that the value is converted before the page submission happens and so the UTC time gets sent always.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3>Create a new schedule</h3>
    <%= bootstrap_form_for(@schedule,label_errors: true, inline_errors: true) do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :title,required:true %>
            <%= f.text_field :description,required:true %>
            <%= f.datetime_local_field :start_time,required:true %>
            <%= f.datetime_local_field :end_time,required:true %>
            <%= f.text_field :cost_cents,required:true %>
            <%= f.button :submit %>
          <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  $('.new_schedule').submit(function() {
  var start_time = moment($('#schedule_start_time').val());

  if (start_time.isValid()) {
    $('#schedule_start_time').val(start_time.clone().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'));
  }

  var end_time = moment($('#schedule_end_time').val());

  if (end_time.isValid()) {
    $('#schedule_end_time').val(end_time.clone().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'));
  }
});
},200);
</script>
```

This article was useful in coming up with this solution..
https://www.codementor.io/yitzofthebits/localize-time-traditional-rails-app-momentjs-twitter-clone-du107wwfg

So when i submit a form with

[image]

the database ends up storing the correct time in UTC.

```
 title  | description |     start_time      |      end_time       
--------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------
 Test 2 | Test 2      | 2018-07-21 12:30:00 | 2018-07-21 14:30:00
```